# Will ARM template deployment overwrite web app certificate?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-resource-manager

I have an Azure Web App where our corp IT has installed an SSL certificate.

I would like to update the app settings with an ARM template. If the ARM template does not contain the SSL certificate, will it be removed from the web app?

We are not using key vault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The certificate will be unlinked, but the certificate resource (invisible on the portal) will remain intact.

Comment: Will it stay linked if I have the hostNameSslStates element with the correct domain name and certificate thumbprint in the ARM template?

Answer (score 1):

Arm templates are designed to be idempotent, that is, if a resources exists it will not be deleted, but configuration changes are applied if the template has been changed, linked resources like an SSL cert remain in place.

When you add an SSL thumbprint to an ARM template the thumbprint refers to an SSL certificate that is already uploaded against the resource its used for therefore nothing changes.

Its the principle used behind Continuous Integration / Continuous Deployment process from VSTS. Triggers deploy code amendments automatically to existing resources, ARM templates deploy new resources or amend environmental factors of existing resource , everything still has to work.

Hope that helps.